# Double comment edit boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I went to edit a comment a moment ago, and it completely doubled up the edit box.

A glitch in the matrix?

[image: freehand double comment boxes]

Comment: Confirmed - There are freehand circles.

Comment: ugh, twitpic can't get a link to the image itself so you can embed it in the question?  Try imgur.com next time.

Comment: @Æther - like I said, my mobile broadband won't like that. Feel free to download from twitpic, upload somewhere else, and change the link to an embedded img.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Jon - Chrome 4.0.249.78 on win7, so I guess Jeff will give a "beta not supported" ;-p

Comment: I've seen this *once* with Safari 4.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.2 as well.

Comment: @random, best Edit Summary ever! I found poetry inside the machine :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get quite the same effect - although I briefly thought I did, due to the "Add Comment" box still being present at the same time. I notice that in your picture the Add Comment box *isn't* obviously present - so I wonder if it's actually the same issue, but showing itself in a different form? (e.g. somehow your Add Comment button was renamed to Save Edits)

Personally I think the Add Comment box should be *replaced* by the edit box.

I'm using Chrome 4.0.249.64 (35722) beta on Windows 7, by the way. Also happens with IE8 (still with the buttons being labeled differently though - so not quite the effect you're seeing.)