# Two comment edit boxes opened up

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-edits

Related:

[Double comment edit boxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36569/double-comment-edit-boxes)

Since that question is almost a year old, the screenshot is broken, and it's tagged completed, I can't be sure if this is a duplicate or a new bug. It seems best to just post this as a new question/report.

---

When I started editing my newly placed comment right after posting it, I got two boxes in stead of one.

Here's the series of events:

1. Arrival at the question, there were 0 comments and 1 answer.
2. Started typing the comment.
3. A new answer was posted so a banner informed me of that, I clicked the reload.
4. Typed and entered the comment.
5. The comment was placed and another comment appeared in front of it.
6. I instantly clicked edit as I often do, to slightly rephrase (a strange habit I have).
7. This:
   [image: The two edit boxes]

---

My current browser is Safari (version 5.1.1) and my current operating system is Mac OS X (version 10.6.8).

Here's the question, if it's any help: [How to ask "(a) or (b), not (c)" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114524/a-or-b-not-c)

Comment: That's indeed a new issue.

Comment: This just happened to me too, in the review section. I posted a comment and then clicked edit and two boxes appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened on the review list, on the moderator dashboard, and in the situation you describe. The reason was that when posts are pulled in via an AJAX call, the various comment click events were bound not only on the newly retrieved post, but also on all of those that were already there previously. Thus you suddenly had, for example, two click handlers on the "edit" link. And two handlers make two edit boxes.

Fixed in the next build.