# Two question edit boxes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, editor

When editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126227/generating-csv-using-table-type-data-that-is-returned-from-a-plsql-function) I somehow managed to get two edit boxes, 2 previews etc.

This is the best screen-shot I could manage. I don't think I did anything particularly strange in order to manage this.

[image]

I'm using Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m and Windows 7 (if it's relevant).

Comment: "This question needs a lot of editing. Better give him two edit boxes." -Community

Comment: Heh. Two for the price of one! Special new year offer on SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latency is so much fun.

We were only hiding the post (including edit link) after loading the editor from the server, so with large latency there was opportunity to click the link a number of times.

Now disabling edit if inline-editing is in progress.

You should be seeing this on the next build.

Answer (score 3):

I reproduced it.

That happens when you click twice on the edit button fast.

You can create multitudes of them if you click twice and then click cancel again and again.

Comment: I just tried (not expecting to be fast enough) double-clicking the "edit" link under the question, and ended up with both the question and this answer in edit mode. Second attempt results in the question in edit mode, but the preview is blank.

Comment: Ah, in that case it's related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114537/two-comment-edit-boxes-opened-up, though on question edits and not comments (and not [status-completed])

Answer (score 1):

Tried a couple reproductions.

First attempt: Both the question and the only existing answer went into edit mode. Cancel worked fine on both of them.

Second attempt: Only the question went into edit mode, but the preview box was empty (show/hide preview worked, but the preview suggested the question body was empty). In this case, the Cancel link resulted in this:

[image]

The post was restored to normal, and a bugged-out edit area appeared below it.

Comment: I've just managed to get your second scenario on your post (which is getting overly meta now) but instead of having a dodgy thing after pressing cancel I went back to a normal open edit window, which I then had to cancel.

Comment: Ugh, this is hurting my brain. Enough with the edit-ception!